# Rest api рекурсия

Tags: android, java

Привет всем! Нужна помощь. Необходимо рекурсивно пробежаться по rest api запросам (не знаю точно как правильно выразиться, но вроде верно сказал).

Буду говорить на примере коробок.

К примеру у меня есть главный URL, который имеет вид:

```
"хост:порт/rest/api/получить_коробки"
```

Который возвращает JSON вида:

```
[
{"children": "true", "name": "Коробка 1 Уровень 1", "uuid" : "49d6e270-10d7-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"}, 
{"children": "true", "name": "Коробка 2 Уровень 1", "uuid: "67bb78f0-10d7-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"}, 
{"children": "true", "name": "Коробка 3 Уровень 1", "uuid : "6ff1d410-10d7-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"}
]
```

(у нас есть 3 коробки, и мы знаем что внутри них еще есть еще коробки, но не знаем сколько именно)

"children": "true" - Это значит, что внутри этой коробки есть еще одна коробка. Соответственно запрос для первой коробки будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
"хост:порт/rest/api/получить_коробки?uuid=49d6e270-10d7-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"
```

Который возвратит например:

```
[
{"children": "true", "name": "Коробка 1 Уровень 2", "uuid" : "3b2b6ec0-10d8-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"}, 
{"children": "false", "name": "Коробка 2 Уровень 2", "uuid: "42841410-10d8-11e4-9191-0800200c9a66"}
]
```

И так далее для каждой коробки.

То есть этих коробок друг в друге может быть большое количество, и мне нужно как-то пробежаться по ним и собрать все данные.

Как это можно реализовать? Знаю, что вроде бы нужно использовать рекурсию, есть у кого-нибудь примеры?

Спасибо!

Comment: > Знаю, что вроде бы нужно использовать рекурсию, есть у кого-нибудь примеры?

А в чем проблема с рекурсией?

Comment: Лучше это реализовать на сервере, на пример с параметром "include_children".     
Если сделать рекурсией на клиенте, скорее всего запрос будут выполняться по несколько минут.

Answer (score 3):

Вообще почитайте про [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), это такое расширение json позволяющее передавать ссылки на связанные объекты без велосипедов. Ну а в чем проблема рекурсивно пройтись по коробкам, не понятно

ЗЫ ну и у вас не совсем REST, но это уже другая песня